# Solve given equation $4^{(x-2)(x+3)} - 64^{(x-3)} = 0?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Solve given equation $4^{(x-2)(x+3)} - 64^{(x-3)} = 0?$

---

My attempt:

I've attempted to solve this question, but isn't it impossible to solve, i.e has already been simplified completely?

$4^{(x-2)(x+3)} - 64^{(x-3)} = 0$

Because $(x-2)(x+3) = x^2 +x - 6?$

So adding those two powers together would mean that they are unable to be solved for $x$?

Thanks

Comment: Is it sure that $-3$ was not in the exponent of $64$?

Comment: @OlivierOloa the edit was incorrect, it was supposed to be 64 to the power of x-3 = 0  :)

Answer (score 7):

From
$$
4^{x^2+x-6}-64^{x-3}=0
$$ you get
$$
2^{2(x^2+x-6)}-2^{6(x-3)}=0
$$ or
$$
2^{2(x^2+x-6)}=2^{6(x-3)}
$$ equivalently

> $$
> 2(x^2+x-6)-6(x-3)=0
> $$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: @Mithlesh Upadhyay Thanks for the good catch!

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Comment: +1 but a "less busy" alternative would be to express $64$ as $4^3$.

Comment: @JohnJoy Good catch! Thanks.